# Solving differential equation $\dot{x}(t)=c\cdot x(t) \cdot (1-x(t))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am pretty new to differential equations and I am having trouble solving the following equation:

$$\dot{x}(t)=c\cdot x(t) \cdot (1-x(t)); \space x(0)=x_0$$

I tried separating the variables:

$$\frac{\dot{x}(t)}{x(t)-(x(t))^2}=c$$

Integrate both sides:

$$\int \frac{\dot{x}(t)}{x(t)-(x(t))^2} dt=\int c dt$$

Substituting $u=x(t)$

$$\int \frac{1}{u-u^2}du=\int c dt\iff \ln(u)-\ln(1-u)+k_1=ct+k_2$$

Exponentiating and grouping constants:

$$e^{\ln(u)}-e^{\ln(1-u)}=e^{ct+K} \iff u-(1-u)=e^{ct+K}$$

Resubstitution:

$$x(t)-(1-x(t))=e^{ct+K}\iff x(t)=\frac{(e^{ct+K}+1)}{2}$$

I tried plugging this back into the original equation but it doesn't work. Mathematica also gives me another solution:

$$\frac{e^{ct}}{e^{ct}+k_1}$$

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: your exponentiation is wrong - $\exp(a-b) = \exp(a)\exp(-b)$ not $\exp(a) - \exp(b)$

Comment: Woops. Thanks I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where am I making a mistake?

After exponentiating:

> Substituting $u=x(t)$
>
> $$\int \frac{1}{u-u^2}du=\int c dt\iff \ln(u)-\ln(1-u)+k_1=ct+k_2$$
>
> Exponentiating and grouping constants:
>
> $$e^{\ln(u)}-e^{\ln(1-u)}=e^{ct+K} \iff u-(1-u)=e^{ct+K}.$$

The last line should be
$$\frac u{1-u}=e^{ct +K} ,    $$

from which we can derive the solutions proposed by Matthematica.

Comment: I always screw up on elementary algebra. Thanks for your help.